# Writing Series as a Telescoping Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Good evening all,

I am faced with this dilemma, and I am hoping someone can help me out.

The series is,

$$\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}
$$

I have figured out the sum to be $\frac{1}{8}$ but I cannot seem to get the expansion as a telescoping series correct

I have tried $\frac{1}{N}$ - $\frac{1}{N-1}$ and $\frac{1}{N+1}$ - $\frac{1}{N}$ but neither work..

If anyone has any idea on how to write the series as a telescoping series that would be greatly appreciated. Any hints or tips are welcome!

[image]

[image]

Comment: $\displaystyle{1\over n(n-1)}={1\over n-1}-{1\over n}$.

Comment: Tried that one as well.. sadly does not work.. @DavidMitra

Comment: That's not $S_N$. It's $t_N$ where $S_N=\sum_{i=9}^N t_N$.

Comment: What do you mean by “does not work”? $\sum_{n=9}^{N}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{9\cdot8}+\frac{1}{10\cdot9}+\frac{1}{11\cdot10}+\cdots\\+\frac{1}{N\cdot(N-1)} = (\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9})+(\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{10})+(\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11})+\cdots+(\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{N})$.

Comment: The quoted material from the book is not right. It should be $S_N=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: What do you mean? @AndréNicolas

Comment: yes, I was mistaken, sorry :(. I realized immediately and deleted my comment.

Comment: I tried it before too it's okay haha @crf

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=9}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=9}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac1n\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac18-\frac1N=\frac18
$$

Comment: please revisit my problem, I tried this and still giving me error.

Comment: Your $S_N$ should be $\frac18-\frac1N$.

Comment: Plugged it in and still incorrect. I see how you got that answer though. I understand it is the good thing.

Answer (score 1):

the general method:

$$
\frac 1{n(n-1)} = \frac An + \frac B{n-1}
\\
B = \lim_1 (n-1)\times \frac 1{n(n-1)} = 1
\\
A =  \lim_0 n\times \frac 1{n(n-1)} = -1
$$

This is why you get $$
\frac 1{n(n-1)} = \frac 1{n-1} - \frac 1n
$$

and then (keep the first term for the lower index and the last with the bigger)
$$
S_N = \sum_{n=9}^N \frac 1{n-1} - \frac 1n = \frac 18 - \frac 1N
$$

Comment: I completely agree with this, however I am still getting an error... ugh

Comment: look at the edit.

Comment: plugged it in and still incorrect... I understand how you got it though..

Comment: what is the definition of $S_N$?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=9}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)} &= \sum_{n=9}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
&=\left(\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{10}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{11}\right) + \dots \\
&=\frac{1}{8} + \left(-\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{9}\right) + \left(-\frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{10}\right) + \dots\\
&=\frac{1}{8}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{n(n - 1)} = \frac{A}{n} + \frac{B}{n - 1} = \frac{A(n - 1) + Bn}{n(n - 1)} = \frac{(A + B)n - A}{n(n + 1)} \\
A + B = 0 \rightarrow A = -B \\
-A = 1 \rightarrow A = -1, B = 1 \\
\frac{1}{n(n - 1)} = \frac{1}{n - 1} - \frac{1}{n}
$$

Now write out some terms:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{9}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{9} - \frac{1}{10}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{11}\right) + ...
$$

It's clear that the $-\frac{1}{n}$ is canceling the next term.  So it should be clear that this gives:

$$
\sum_9^N \left(\frac{1}{n - 1} - \frac{1}{n}\right) = \frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{N}
$$

Now take the limit as $N$ goes to infinity:

$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_9^N \left(\frac{1}{n - 1}- \frac{1}{n}\right) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{8} - \frac{1}{N} = \frac{1}{8}\text{, q.e.d.}
$$